# PCIE SSD Raid0 not bootable but everything is OK on it

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd, raid

I have a MSI GT72S 6QE laptop where the OS (Windows 10) is installed on a PCIE RAID0 SSD (I know, Raid0 sucks, I won't make that mistake again when buying a laptop).
On of the two SSD's in the RAID kept getting not recognized at all, the room temperature seemed to be the reason (I know how it sounds but everytime my room got under 20°C the SSD wasn't recognized) but it also happened seemingly at random.
I then would have to reboot my computer a number of times for the SSD to be found and then everything would work absolutely fine.

I got tired of it so I opened the laptop and reseated the SSD's in the RAID structure and booted my computer.
One of the disks was marked as "Error Occured" in the "Intel Rapid Storage" section of my BIOS but besides that every test I could find told me the RAID was OK.
I installed another windows on an HDD that was also in the computer so I could mark the drive as normal in "Intel Optane".

[Here is the drive that was marked as error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swHXA.png)

[Here is the other :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIrMt.png)

[Here is the raid, and when I do "Verify", it passes 100%:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cqoX.png)

Now in the BIOS both SSDs are marked as "RAID member" and the RAID is in status OK and Bootable "Yes".
After that I did every volume test available, TestDisk can see EVERY file in the Windows partition and the boot manager still sees a Windows boot on that volume but when I try to boot on that Windows, I just get a black screen.

[Here is the disk in TestDisk:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xziac.png)

[What's in the RAID is all OK, Windows is in "OS_Install", obviously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7RNM.png)

[And here are the contents of OS_Install:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NqXk.png)

Chkdsk finds no error at all. TestDisk doesn't see any lost partition and tells me the boot record and backup boot record are fine and yet I can't neither boot on that windows or repair it, when I try the "Startup Repair" the laptop reboots and MSI tells me "checking drive for errors, this could take hours" but stops after a few minutes and reboots.
If I try to reinstall windows from the Cloud ou local image it says right away that there is a problem without saying more and goes to the previous screen.
I'm at my wit's end. If the SSD was really dead, could I do everything I did above? I don't think so but I'm not a pro.

In the other windows installed on the HDD, the drive appears as the letter "D" and isn't accessible, it tells me "access denied" if I try to go in, but TestDisk can with no problem and chkdsk can find and test every volume in the RAID.

What is maddening is that both SSD's seem absolutely fine, the RAID too, Optane, testdisk, chkdsk, etc. find no error and the boot manager sees my windows install on the RAID but cannot boot or repair it, I'm at a total loss.
I can't believe that the SSD is dead and yet I can acess and copy every file on the volume with TestDisk, but I don't know what to do next.

I need help guys, I feel like it's a little stupid thing like remaking the boot record or something (but it's GPT, not MBR, and I don't know much about either) like that and I would be able to boot on it no problem.
I really don't want to restart on a fresh windows but if I have to I will, but I don't know how to do even that, the RAID seems both fine and failed at the same time.

Thanks for reading, I really hope I can find a way to redeem that drive.

UPDATE:

I've tried to fix the windows install with sfc /scannow with offbootdir=D:\ and offwindir=D:\Windows\ from the Windows Boot USB command prompt, it fixed errors successfully but I still get a black screen when trying to boot on that Windows.

So I tried DISM to fix the install, with a DISM /Image: D:\offline //Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth with the install.esd from the USB as source but I get an error 2 (or 5 depending on the command) telling me "Unable to access the image", so then again the drive seems OK but can't be accessed by "elevated" tools, but "low level" tools can see every file and doesn't find any errors...
It's maddening seriously.

Is there a disk attribute (diskpart doesen't see it as readonly, I checked) or something that I missed?

Please anyone, help! I just can't get over the fact that the disk seems OK with every tool I use, it has to be something small that's wrong with it.

PS:

When I first opened the laptop I didn't note the order of the SSD's in the RAID "structure", and I switched them from their ports several time, so I don't remember at all in which order (there are only two ports where the disk can fit on that "structure") they where.
If I have put them back in the wrong order, could I still access the files on the partition?

Furthermore, **and I think it's the whole problem**, from the command prompt when I boot on the windows USB, I can do dir d:\windows and it shows me the files, but if I do dir d:\ it tells me "access denied", and finally, if I type dir d: it marks:

Volume in drive D is OS_Install
Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX (hidden by me)

Directory of D:\ 
File not found

Does that mean anything to you guys?

PS2:

I just used MiniTools Partition Wizard on the other Windows installed on the HDD, it sees the RAID perfectly, sees all the partitions OK like testdisk does.
I did a surface test on the whole disk and on individual partitions, it passed with flying colors. Re-did a chkdsk on the OS_Install partition just in case but 0 errors again.
I can explore the partition also with MiniTools and I can see everything where it's supposed to be.
TestDisk tells me the boot record and mft are both OK and perfectly matched to their backup/mirror.

DiskGenius sees both TOSHIBA SSD's OK, the SMART info is all marked Good and when I compare all the infos on both disk they seem to match except for the "Total Host Read/Total Host Writes" values, is that normal (I'm presuming it's the amount of data written on each disk right?)
I did a bad track search that gave me all Excellent, Good or Normal tracks/cylinders. (Most of them Excellent, around 10K good and 3 Normal, no bad tracks found).
Again it also sees every file in the main partition and can even explore the SYSTEM and WinRe partitions and they look OK to me.

That's one hell of a headscratcher! If one of the SSD's or the RAID are really damaged then could I do all this?
But then if they're OK, what the hell is locking the main partition like that?

Comment: I assume the D partition is the system disk on the RAID while booted in another Windows installation? Being unable to view the contents of a system disk from System A on System B is not all that strange.  Windows respects the permissions of Windows.  However, it saying "inaccessible" tells something happened to the RAID.  Since you were using RAID 0 this basically means the data is indeed inaccessible.

Comment: Yes exactly, when booted from the Windows 10 I installed on the HDD. (My laptop has a RAID0 as system drive and a 1To HDD as an additional drive).

Comment: To be clear it says "Access denied" in the Explorer, but TestDisk has no problems getting into it from that Windows.